# I couldn't open style file IEEEbib.bst

Tags: latex

I am trying to complete a paper in `latex` downloaded from an online template.

there shows an error while compiling:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.6)
The top-level auxiliary file: Islam2021.aux
I couldn't open style file IEEEbib.bst
---line 69 of file Islam2021.aux
 : \bibstyle{IEEEbib
 :                  }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file Islam2021.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you try with https://2021.ieeeicassp.org/Papers/PaperFormat/IEEEbib.bst in the same folder as your .tex file?

Comment: This question is asking about `IEEEbib.bst`, a non-standard IEEE bibliography file.  In contrast, the more common `IEEEtran.bst` is easy to find at official sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEEEbib.bst` is not a default style include in tex distributions. Either you can download it from wherever you have your online template from or you could try your luck with a random version of the file from somewhere on the internet, e.g.

https://web.archive.org/web/20201026100503/https://2021.ieeeicassp.org/Papers/PaperFormat/IEEEbib.bst

(this might be a different version and might give different results ...)

Comment: the link is down,  you can get the file in the `ctan page`: [direct link](http://tug.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.bst)

Comment: @A.Casanova That's not the same file

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswer.xyz I am sorry, you are right. The link above leads to the file `IEEEtran.bst`.  It is the updated version of the file asked in this question. There are 3 files: `ieeetr.bst`  (1985/1988), `IEEEbib.bst` (1993), `IEEEtran.bst` (2003) but version v1.14 (2015). Just FYI. PD thanks for updating the link

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the desired '.bst' file was included inside a folder in the '.zip' of the downloaded LATEX template. All I had to do was to move it out to the root directory.